# 'str' object is not callable- tic_tac_toe- Pytnon

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to make a tic tac toe game and I get:

> 'str' object is not callable

as error. No idea what to do.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output 

def display_board (board):

    clear_output() 
    print (' ' + board [7] + '|' + board [8] + '|' + board[9])
    print (' ' + board [4] + '|' + board [5] + '|' + board[6])
    print (' ' + board [1] + '|' + board [2] + '|' + board[3])

def player_input(): 

    marker = " "
    while marker != "X" and marker != "O": 

        marker = input ('Igralec 1: izberi X ali O: ').upper()
    
    if marker == 'X':
        return ('X', 'O')
    else:
        return ('O', 'X')

def place_marker (board, marker, position):
 
    board[position]= marker

def win_check (board, mark):    
  
    return ((board[1] == board[2] == board[3] == mark) or #vrsta 1
    (board[4] == board[5] == board[6] == mark) or #vrsta 2
    (board[5] == board[6] == board[7] == mark) or #vrsta 3 
    (board[8] == board[5] == board[2] == mark) or #stolpec 2
    (board[9] == board[6] == board[3] == mark) or #stolpec 3 
    (board[7] == board[4] == board[1] == mark) or #stolpec 4
    (board[3] == board[5] == board[7] == mark) or #diagonala
    (board[1] == board[5] == board[9] == mark)) #diagonala

import random 

def choose_first():

    flip= random.randint (0,1)   
    if flip== 0:
        return 'Igralec 1'    
    else:
        return 'Player 2'

def space_check (board, position): 

    board[position] ==' '

def full_board_check (board):
    
    for i in range (1,10):
        if space_check (board, i):
            return False
    
    return True

def player_choice (board): 
    
    position= 0 
    while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not space_check (board, position):
        position = int(input('Izberi pozicijo: (1-9) '))
    
    return position 

def replay(): 
    
    choice = input ('Želiš še enkrat igrat (Y or N)? ')    
    return choice ('Y')

print (' Hello, pri tri v vrsto!')

while True:
    
    the_board=[""] *10
    player1_marker,player2_marker = player_input()
    
    turn= choose_first()
    print= (turn+ ' je prvi igralec!')
    
    play_game= input (' Pripravljeni za igro? y or n ')
    
    if play_game== 'y':
        game_on= True
    else:
        game_on= False
    
    ##game time
        
    while game_on:
        #igralec 1 
        if turn== 'Player 1':
        
            display_board(the_board)
           
            position= player_choice(the_board)
          
            place_marker(the_board,player1_marker,position)
            
            #check if they won
            if win_check(the_board,player1_marker):
                display_board(the_board)
                print ('Igralec 1 je zmagovalec!')
                game_on = False
            
            else:
                if full_board_check(the_board):
                    display_board(the_board)
                    print ("Izanačeno!")
                    game_on= False
                else:
                    turn = 'Igralec 2'
                
        else: 
            #igralec 2 
            
            display_board(the_board)
         
            position= player_choice(the_board)
            
            place_marker(the_board,player2_marker,position)
            
            #check if they won
            if win_check(the_board,player2_marker):
                display_board(the_board)
                print ('Igralec 2 je zmagovalec!')
                game_on = False
            
            else:
                if full_board_check(the_board):
                    display_board(the_board)
                    print ("Izanačeno!")
                    game_on= False
                else:
                    turn = 'Igralec 1'
    
    if not replay():
        break
```

Errors are:

> ```
> 49             display_board(the_board)
> \AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10492/3794783463.py in display_board(board)
> print (' ' + board [7] + '|' + board [8] + '|' + board[9])
>
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>
> TypeError
>
>  1 print (' Hello pri tri v vrsto!')
>  2 
>  3 while True:
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: looks like you have a rogue equals - `print= (turn+ ' je prvi igralec!')`

Comment: You assign "print" to a string. You should never use names of builtin functions as variable names.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
print= (turn+ ' je prvi igralec!')
```

Should be written like this:

```
print(turn+ ' je prvi igralec!')
```

You can find what goes wrong with the error description hints ;)

Answer (score -1):

You have the typo `=` in `print()`, the fix would be:

```py
print(turn + ' je prvi igralec!')
```

to prevent such cases install the linter, like `flake8` or `pylint`, they could help you to improve your code. Also check the `black` formatting tool to improve readability.